# Microsoft Ribbon for WPF (4.0.0.11019)

Tags: wpf, ribbon-control

I am using the latest WPF Ribbon control downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4&displaylang=en
In Windows XP, the Ribbon application window’s title bar looks like from Windows 98… or like from console window. How can I improve the appearance of tittle bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answered by a Microsoft Consultant:**
The RibbonWindow ships with three templates as of the October 2010 release - Classic, Aero Basic, and Aero with glass. On XP's Luna theme, we fall back to displaying the Classic look for the RibbonWindow. It should be fairly easy to retemplate RibbonWindow to achieve the native XP look - use our RibbonWindow templates in the [Ribbon Source and Samples MSI](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4&displaylang=en) as an example. If we get feedback from several customers that the Luna theme is a top request, we will definitely consider including that for our next release.

Comment: I get `We're sorry, this download is no longer available.`, how do i get?