# Ribbon Control showing Windows 2000 Minimise/Maximise/Close buttons

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, ribbon

I'm trying to get a standard Ribbon Control working using VS 2010 on Windows XP. I've downloaded/installed the latest version of the Ribbon Control (October 2010) from the [Microsoft Download Centre](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2BFC3187-74AA-4154-A670-76EF8BC2A0B4&displaylang=en). From here I created a new project with the "WPF Ribbon Application" template.

The control itself works fine, but it seems to apply the Windows 2000 theme to the Minimise/Maximise/Close buttons, as can be seen in this screenshot:

[image: Ribbon Control with Windows 2k styles for top right windows controls]

I've tried changing the main window style to Aero in app.xaml (no effect on top right controls). I also tried (and failed) to set the Ribbon style to Office2007 (apparently the most recent version of the ribbon control has [removed this feature](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/bdd38687-4183-48bb-a982-0b8da5d82b9a)).

Did I install something incorrectly? I installed both the *.msi files in the link. Am I missing a reference?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can check the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184191/microsoft-ribbon-for-wpf-4-0-0-11019

Comment: Thanks for the link, it looked like it was pointing me in the right direction, but I failed to get its solution (retemplating the window) to work. No matter how I set the theme (in App.xaml, MainWindow.xaml and programatically) I couldn't get the desired result, i.e. get rid of the rubbish "Classic Windows" Windows controls. I did learn a lot about how to access themes from different assemblies though, so it was still quite useful. But question remains unanswered.

Comment: edited my answer, this is still popping up every time in Google, please accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I know this is an old question but he this pops up in Google so for all the people that will see this in the future!

ANSWER DOWN HERE!!!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21675624/3239917

Instead of the tags `<ribbon:RibbonWindow` on the beginning of the xaml,
Make it `<Window` .

Then in your class delete your `: RibbonWindow`

After that go back to your XAML, and change the Ribbon margin to -22 :

```
 <r:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RibbonRegion" Margin="0,-22,0,0" >
```