# WPF window border acting weird with Ribbon Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism, ribbon

I am using the Ribbon control in WPF and I noticed there are 2 different versions.

1. using Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;

   - If I use this one in my xaml and class, my whole window will be in a very old windows style.
2. using System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;

   - If I use this one in my xaml and class, my Ribbontabs suddenly won't fill correctly anymore.

When I use both of them. With this:

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow x:Class="WPSDashboard.Views.ShellWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"
        xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary" 
        xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism" 
        Title="WPSDashboard"
        x:Name="RibbonWindow"
        Width="640" Height="480">


    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Ribbon Region -->
        <r:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RibbonRegion">
            <r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                <r:RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Images\SmallIcon.png">
                    <r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Exit"
                                                      x:Name="MenuItemExit"
                                                      ImageSource="Images\Exit.png"
                                                      Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"/>
                    </r:RibbonApplicationMenu>
            </r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        </r:Ribbon>

        <Grid x:Name="ClientArea" Grid.Row="1">                   

            <!-- Workspace Region-->
            <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <ContentControl x:Name="WorkspaceRegion" Grid.Column="1" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="WorkspaceRegion" />
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
    </ribbon:RibbonWindow>
```

My Ribbontabs will load but the window now looks like this:
I can't click on close and minimize and maximize. <---

[image: Screenshot]

How can I get the border to be normal instead of small?
I can't close my windows this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the best way to make it look and work good!

Instead of the tags `<ribbon:RibbonWindow` on the beginning of the xaml,
Make it `<Window` .
Also add this part:

```
xmlns:r="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"
```

Then in your class delete your `: RibbonWindow` (If it's there)

If that doesn't work and you don't need the quick access toolbar, this may help:
Go back to your XAML, and change the Ribbon margin to -22 :

```
 <r:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RibbonRegion" Margin="0,-22,0,0" >
```

Now my application looks like this(with the -22 margin) :
[image]

Now it looks like a normal application without an ugly windows 98 or 2000 style and the close button, minizime button and maximize button are back!

Comment: Which ruins the quick links of the ribbon window. It's not a complete solution.

Comment: I don't know how this was fixed anymore but i saw your comment and went back to this old project. I noticed that I don't have to use the -22 margin for it to work. I will edit my answer.

Comment: It would be nice if your tried this solution again. I edited the answer. If this doesn't work in your situation there has to be something else that is wrong. This is just a solution to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would, either play on margins, or better than that, investigate the style of that ribbon and change it the way it helps my needs

Comment: Thanks for looking into my question,
but the problem is that I can't click on the close button, maximize button and minimize button.

Comment: Yes I can see that, try to play on the height of the ribon or it's margins by changing the style of the ribbon object using Expression Blend for Visual Studio

Comment: For some reason the control acts different when I use the :
using System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon; library.
Thanks for your answer! I changed the top margin and now it does fit.
I feel stupid for not finding this before. :D